# Does any IDE fully support v38+ (Winter 17)

Tags: ide

Has anyone had any luck with any IDE since winter 17? I used to be a big supporter of Mavens Mate but the new server and desktop app are just bad, poorly supported and doesn't work with all metadata anymore.

I've tried Eclipse and even Illuminated Cloud(paid) and a few other smaller ones and it seems that no one supports the changes in v38. In particular Salesforce changed picklist value definitions to Value Sets and moved the standard picklist (IE: Case Origin) into a new metadata type called [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm), I can't find any IDE that will actually pull the standard value set files from the server. I've resorted to using ant migration tool and a set of package builder scripts but that isn't scale-able for actual development and managing project teams.

All we really need is a simple IDE that syncs all metadata types local <-> server that uses the standard folder structure (no Welkin Suite).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53140/discussion-on-question-by-stephen-does-any-ide-fully-support-v38-winter-17).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 1.7.8.0, Illuminated Cloud provides full-cycle development support for StandardValueSet.

Answer (score 1):

An API 38 package was released on Friday 02/03/17 by the team for Eclipse. It should be available from the usual download link. I've installed it at the end of the day on Friday and haven't done anything with it yet to tell you what all it supports.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53176/discussion-on-answer-by-crmprogdev-does-any-ide-fully-support-v38-winter-17).